# Efficiently sort a list of objects that logically are part of the same entity

Tags: java, performance, sorting, data-structures, collections

I have a series of objects that I want to sort in a specific way.
Example:
I have the class `Employee` that has an attribute `departmentId`.
So many instances of `Employee` objects have the same value for `departmentId`.
An employee also has a salary attribute.
So I have a `List<Employee> employees` objects that I want to sort so that the sorting order is as follows:
The employee with the lowest salary is first in the list followed by all the other employees sorted by salary **of the same department**.
Then after the last employee of that department I want the next department who has an employee with less salary than all other departments and the rest of the employees sorted etc.
E.g.

```
(John, 10000, A)   
(Jane, 30000, A)  
(Bill, 32000, A)  
(Jim, 12000, B)  
(Jake, 50000, B)  
(James, 14000, C)
```

etc

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this? I want to make the code as compact and efficient as possible rather than creating temporary anonymous classes to add them to hash maps (unless that is the only efficient way).

**Note:**
I know about comparators and comparable etc.
My question is not about how to actually do the sorting (I know implement comparator) **but** how can code like this be efficiently done preferably avoiding a bunch of temporary anonymous objects

**Also:** I am not using Java 8 and would like a plain Java approach

**Update:**
In response to comments. I want the department with the lowest salary first then the next highest etc

Comment: Anything wrong with `Collections.sort`?

Comment: Comparator/Comparable are the proper ways to go IMHO. It is not about a bunch of temporary anonymous objects - just either make Employee implement Comparable or create a single instance of Comparator

Comment: @ReutSharabani:It is not just sorting but also grouping

Comment: Still, I don't see the reason why you shouldn't simply implement a Comparator for this and call Collections.sort... The comparator compares department by id first, if equals, then the salary. Simple.

Comment: @Jim i think it is not about grouping - simple sort by department first and by salary after

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz:I never said I don't want to implement a comparator. Please read the OP. This is about sorting **AFTER** grouping

Comment: @bedring:If I sort by department first and then by salary how can I make sure that I end up with the order I ask? I want the department **with** the lowest salary first

Comment: Sorry, still don't get the problem. The comparator does not have to be anonym and it will be one extra object. Not " a bunch".

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz:May be I am confused or overcomplicate things. Can you give an answer with a snippet so that I understand what you are suggesting? What I need is the department with the lowest salary first(sorted also) then the department with the next highest salary (sorted also) etc

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz The problem is the order of the departments. They are not sorted by ID. Their order relies on information that isn't in the department object but requires looking up all its associated employees.

Comment: Yep, sorry, understood that just now. That makes it a little bit more tricky, agreed and there I can see the bunch of objects popping up, if you don't want a department objects (or lists for that).

Comment: [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) is `n log(n)` (excluding the complexity of the `Comparator`), which should be enough for most applications.

Comment: Personally I would probably go for the easy way first, group them in a HashMapList (or something like that by department id -> list<Employee>), sort the lists and the combine the results again, sorted by the first value of the list and then test if it's fast enough. Optimize only if it isn't.

Comment: @RealSkeptic:Yes, that is my question. I was thinking that if I order by department and then by salaries, I would need an efficient way to "move" these department blocks to their proper location even to a new array list. But I would need to know the start and ending indexes of each department in the list which I don't know how to do it efficiently. I mean if I do linear search or binary search or the code will become too complicated and error prone

Comment: @Jim, I think the most efficient way would be to create one hash map and one comparator based on it. I'm not sure why you are so against creating additional objects, though.

Comment: @RealSkeptic:Because the approach that I suggested seems very simple without needing extra objects except the part I got stuck with. That is why I was wondering what's the best way

Comment: The part where you got stuck is exactly what makes it not very simple...

Comment: @downvoters:Please leave a comment. Downvoting is constructive if a comment is also given

Comment: Where does the data come from? If from a relational database, the most efficient way to do the sorting is probably to let the DB handle it.

Comment: @MickMnemonic:No unfortunately not. They come from a server but I can't affect the ordering

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd use an `Employee` class and `Department` class, both would extend the [`Comparable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface to make use of library functionality.

Here is an example of a Department class which has a name and a list of employees, which are sorted upon construction. You may want to shallow-copy the list on `getEmployees()` to prevent others from altering it's order:

```
class Department implements Comparable<Department> {

    private List<Employee> employees;
    private char name;

    public Department(char name, List<Employee> employees) {
        // avoid mutating original list
        this.employees = new ArrayList<Employee>(employees);
        this.name = name;

        Collections.sort(this.employees);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Department other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        // employees are sorted by salary within their department.
        // all we need is to compare the lowest-salary employees
        // from both departments
        return this.employees.get(0).getSalary()
                - other.employees.get(0).getSalary();
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return this.employees;
    }

    public char getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Now `Employee` class only has to implement [`compareTo(Employee other)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) with the salary comparison:

```
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public Employee(String name, int salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return this.salary - other.salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [name=" + name + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

}
```

This should allow you to use [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) on lists of departments and get the right order. Here is a full blown example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Fiddles {

    static class Department implements Comparable<Department> {

        private List<Employee> employees;
        private char name;

        public Department(char name, List<Employee> employees) {
            // avoid mutating original list
            this.employees = new ArrayList<Employee>(employees);
            this.name = name;

            Collections.sort(this.employees);
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Department other) {
            if (other == null) {
                return 1;
            }
            return this.employees.get(0).getSalary()
                    - other.employees.get(0).getSalary();
        }

        public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
            return this.employees;
        }

        public char getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    static class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

        private String name;
        private int salary;

        public Employee(String name, int salary) {
            this.name = name;
            this.salary = salary;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Employee other) {
            if (other == null) {
                return 1;
            }
            return this.salary - other.salary;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employee [name=" + name + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final Department A = new Department('A', new ArrayList<Employee>() {
            {
                add(new Employee("John", 10000));
                add(new Employee("Jane", 30000));
                add(new Employee("Bill", 32000));
            }
        });
        final Department B = new Department('B', new ArrayList<Employee>() {
            {
                add(new Employee("Jim", 12000));
                add(new Employee("Jake", 50000));
            }
        });

        final Department C = new Department('C', new ArrayList<Employee>() {
            {

                add(new Employee("James", 14000));

            }
        });

        List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<Department>() {
            {
                add(A);
                add(B);
                add(C);
            }
        };
        Collections.shuffle(departments);
        Collections.sort(departments);
        for (Department department : departments) {
            for (Employee e : department.getEmployees()) {
                System.out.println(String.format(
                        "Employee: %s, Salary: %d, department: %s",
                        e.getName(), e.getSalary(), department.getName()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the simplest way is to:

1. Prepare a `Map` from each department ID to the minimum salary in that department. This requires scanning once through the list (O(n)).
2. Make a comparator that uses that map. It's just a single object. The comparator sorts such that:

   - If two employees are in the same department, compare their salaries.
   - If the two departments are different, compare their minimum salaries based on the above map.
   - If they have the same rank (lowest salary), sort by their IDs (otherwise you might get two departments with the same lowest salary mixed).
   - Otherwise compare their ranks.

So here is a demonstration (**Edit**: the operations are now encapsulated in the `Employee` class. The work it does is the same, though):

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int salary;
    private String department;


    /**
     * Comparator - Note that it has a constructor that takes a department ranking
     * list, which should be prepared in advance
     */
    private static class DepartmentAndSalaryComparator implements Comparator<Employee>{

        Map<String,Integer> departmentRanking;

        public DepartmentAndSalaryComparator(Map<String,Integer> departmentRanking) {
            this.departmentRanking = departmentRanking;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {

            // If employees belong to the same department, rank them by salary

            if ( o1.department.equals(o2.department )) {
                return o1.salary - o2.salary;
            }

            // Get the lowest salaries for the departments of the respective employees

            int o1Rank = departmentRanking.get(o1.department);
            int o2Rank = departmentRanking.get(o2.department);

            if ( o1Rank == o2Rank ) {
                return o1.department.compareTo(o2.department);
            }

            return o1Rank - o2Rank;

        }
    }

    public Employee(String name, int salary, String department) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.department = department;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a map of department id to minimum salary in that department
     * from a given list of employees.
     * This operation is O(n)
     * @param employees List of employees for which to calculate map
     * @return Map of department rankings
     */
    private static Map<String,Integer> calculateDepartmentRanking( List<Employee> employees ) {
        Map<String,Integer> rankings = new HashMap<>();

        for ( Employee emp : employees ) {
            Integer currMin = rankings.get(emp.department);
            if ( currMin == null || currMin > emp.salary ) {
                rankings.put(emp.department, emp.salary);
            }
        }
        return rankings;
    }

    /**
     * Static method to sort a list of employees by Department, then by Salary, where
     * the order of department is based on the minimum salary in that department.
     * This operation is O(n log n)
     * 
     * @param employees The list of employees to sort
     */
    public static void sortListBySalaryBasedDepartment( List<Employee> employees ) {
        Collections.sort(employees, new DepartmentAndSalaryComparator(calculateDepartmentRanking(employees)));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Employee: name=%s, salary=%d, dept.=%s",
                             name,
                             salary,
                             department);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       // Create example list and shuffle it to make sure it's not ordered

        List<Employee> employees = Arrays.asList(
                new Employee("Millie", 12000, "Accounts"),
                new Employee("Morris", 21200, "Accounts"),
                new Employee("Jerry", 22000, "Accounts"),
                new Employee("Ellen", 17000, "Sales"),
                new Employee("Sandy", 12500, "Technology"),
                new Employee("Jack", 40000, "Technology")
           );

        Collections.shuffle(employees);

        // Sort using the special comparator

        Employee.sortListBySalaryBasedDepartment(employees);

        for (Employee e : employees) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Employee: name=Millie, salary=12000, dept.=Accounts
Employee: name=Morris, salary=21200, dept.=Accounts
Employee: name=Jerry, salary=22000, dept.=Accounts
Employee: name=Sandy, salary=12500, dept.=Technology
Employee: name=Jack, salary=40000, dept.=Technology
Employee: name=Ellen, salary=17000, dept.=Sales
```